# Testing Websites with Espresso & Android Studio

Tags: android, mobile, android-studio, android-browser, android-espresso

I want to test a few websites on the Android Standard Browser. I'm using Android Studio and Espresso (which I set up using Double Espresso as instructed [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso)).

I'm rather new to Android Studio and Espresso, but I'm familiar with IntelliJ and Selenium. All tutorials I've found have been for testing apps, I just want to test websites. Importing the Android Browser's code into my project seems a rather radical step, if it's even possible.

I'm aware that there are other technologies I could use for mobile testing, including Selenium, but I need to use Espresso for this project.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Espresso also support you to test the web inside an application (WebView) and it is very familiar to testing a native app, for more detail see this link below:

https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/web/index.html

And yes there are very few tutorials about Espresso test for web, my advise is try to do some demo test with Espresso in native app then you will figure out how to use it on the web.

Hope it help.